# Array of pointers to structs - why is malloc() required, why is direct field copies required?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding about memory and pointers in C. I'd like to ask why an array of pointers to structs needs `malloc()` called for individual elements of the array even though I'd think if they're getting initialized individually, then memory should be automatically allocated for them. Second, when filling up the array of pointers, it seems that it's necessary to copy the elements of the structs individually and simply copying the pointer to the struct itself doesn't work.

In other programs, I've been using structs and pointers a bit and I keep having to figure out the correct way to implement them, so I'd like to understand it intuitively rather than just taking for word "you just need to `malloc()` individual elements of the array"

```
/* suppose I have "typedef struct coord { int x; int y; } coord;" */
int num_rooms = 5;
coord* coordinates[num_rooms];
int i, j;
/* why is this required? in the following loop, coord[i] gets initialized,
and I thought memory automatically gets allocated on the stack because of 
the initialization */
for (i = 0; i < num_rooms; i++) {
    coordinates[i] = (coord*) malloc(sizeof(coord));
}
/* fill the array of coord pointers */
for (j = 0; j < num_rooms; j++) {
    coord coordinate;
    coord *coord_p;
    coord_p = &coordinate;
    coord_p->x = j;
    coord_p->y = j;

    /* this does not work. It just makes all array elements have the same struct elements. (the second question) Why does it require copying over individual field elements instead of copying the pointer?*/
    //coordinates[j] = coord_p;

     /* however, assigning individual elements doesn't cause segmentation fault */
     coordinates[j]->x = coord_p->x;
     coordinates[j]->y = coord_p->y;
}
```

If I uncomment `coordinates[i] = coord_p;` it ends up that all elements of the array have struct elements of the last initialized one. So if I printed every coordinate[i]->x and coordinate[i]->y it would saying '4 4' 5 times. But when I used the direct struct element copy, I get the correct output of '0 0, 1 1, 2 2, ...' if I printed it.

I expect that it should be fine to not allocate memory for individual elements of the array since they are initialized in a loop. I also expect that `coordinates[i] = coord_p;` should copy over the pointers value, letting something like `printf("%d", coordinates[0]->x);` work properly. However, in both cases I'm clearly misunderstanding something.

Comment: Why do you think you need an array of pointers to individual structs? Usually you can just make an array of structs, and that removes the need for per struct allocation entirely.

Comment: Because the array is of pointers to structs. Those pointers are uninitialized until allocated or assigned

Comment: I have a function that returns a struct pointer instead of the struct. Then I have a need for storing all those structs in an array, so I make a array of pointers to structs. The reason being that (from my understanding) it's more efficient to return pointers rather than the whole object. And then when I need to collect all those returned values, I end up needing to collect the pointers.

Comment: You are confusing separate issues: array of pointers, and some struct objects you can point to. You need to initialize these pointers to point to *something*. It does *not* have to be something allocated with *malloc* (though it often is, because you often need to allocate them dynamically at the runtime).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...why an array of pointers to structs needs malloc() called for individual elements of the array even though I'd think if they're getting initialized individually, then memory should be automatically allocated for them.

The simple answer is that *C never allocates anything for you "automatically" in this sense.*

One way to think about it is that C allocates just enough memory for your named variables, and that's it.  If you say

```
int i;
```

C allocates enough memory for one `int`.  If you say

```
double a[10];
```

C allocates enough memory for 10 `double`s.  If you say

```
int *p;
```

C allocates enough memory for one pointer-to-int, *but* it does not allocate any memory for that pointer to point to!

Almost without exception, when you declare pointers, it's your responsibility to think about the allocation of the memory that your pointers will point to.  C never does that for you automatically.

In your specific example, when you said

```
coord* coordinates[5];
```

C allocated space for 5 pointers to `coord` -- but it allocated space for zero actual instances of `coord`.  If, on the other hand, you had said

```
coord coordinatesa[5];
```

C would have allocated space for 5 actual instances of `coord` -- although you'd obviously use this array quite differently, since there are no pointers involved.

When you allocated 5 pointers, but no actual instances of `coord`, if you had tried to use one of the pointers, it would have been a serious error:

```
coord* coordinates[5];
coordinates[0]->x = 1;       /* WRONG */
coordinates[0]->y = 2;       /* WRONG */
```

One way to fix this would be to first make sure that `coordinates[0]` points somewhere:

```
coord* coordinates[5];
coordinates[0] = malloc(sizeof(coord));
coordinates[0]->x = 1;       /* better */
coordinates[0]->y = 2;       /* better */
```

> Second, when filling up the array of pointers, it seems that it's necessary to copy the elements of the structs individually and simply copying the pointer to the struct itself doesn't work.

Ah, but when you copy pointers, you're carrying along the allocation of the source pointer, and losing the allocation of the destination pointer.

Taking my preceding example, and blending in part of your program, if you were to say

```
coord* coordinates[5];
coordinates[0] = malloc(sizeof(coord));

coord coordinate;
coord *coord_p;
coord_p = &coordinate;
coord_p->x = 1;
coord_p->y = 2;
coordinates[0] = coord_p;
```

This will "work", but it's wasteful and probably wrong.  The memory allocated by the `malloc` call is never used, and when you say

```
coordinates[0] = coord_p;
```

the old pointer is overwritten and the pointed-to memory (that `malloc` so kindly gave you!) is lost.

After this assignment, the allocation of the memory pointed to by `coordinates[0]` is whatever `coord_p`'s allocation was, which in this case is the single `coord` structure `coordinate`.  As I say, this might seem to "work" at first, but if `coordinate` is a local variable that goes out of scope, or if you end up re-using it for all 5 coordinates in your `coordinates` array, you're going to have problems.

If, on the other hand, you say

```
*coordinates[0] = *coord_p;
```

or, equivalently,

```
coordinates[0]->x = coord_p->x;
coordinates[0]->y = coord_p->y;
```

now you're fetching data from the `coord` pointed to by `coord_p`, and safely copying it to the memory pointed to by `coordinates[0]`.  Having done so, you've (a) properly used the memory you allocated for `coordinates[0]` to point to, and (b) insulated yourself from whatever happens later to the memory pointed to by `coord_p`.

But having gotten this far, in this case, we don't have to use the intermediate `coord_p` pointer at all.  We could just as well say

```
coord coordinate;
coordinate.x = 1;
coordinate.y = 2;

*coordinates[0] = coordinate;
```

or, equivalently,

```
coordinates[0]->x = coordinate.x;
coordinates[0]->y = coordinate.y;
```

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to ask why an array of pointers to structs needs malloc()
>   called for individual elements of the array even though I'd think if
>   they're getting initialized individually, then memory should be
>   automatically allocated for them.

It really isn't much different from having one pointer and allocating memory for it using `malloc`. Except instead of one pointer you have a whole array of pointers, so instead of just doing it once, you do it for each element of the array.

There's a problem with this part:

```
for (j = 0; j < num_rooms; j++) {
    coord coordinate;
    coord *coord_p;
    coord_p = &coordinate;
    coordinates[j] = coord_p;
}
```

`coord coordinate` is not dynamically allocated, so it's only valid until the end of the scope. At the end of the `for` loop, it becomes invalid. You save its pointer in `coord_p` and write that pointer to your array, but those pointers are all invalid afterwards.

But you already allocated memory for all the pointers, so you don't need to allocate any more. Just do this:

```
for (j = 0; j < num_rooms; j++) {
    coordinates->x = j;
    coordinates->y = j;
}
```

---

```
 /* however, assigning individual elements doesn't cause segmentation fault */
 coordinates[j]->x = coord_p->x;
 coordinates[j]->y = coord_p->y;
```

The reason why this part works is that you're copying over the values of `coord` to your `coordinates` objects. Sure, `coord` becomes invalid at the end of the loop, but you made a copy of the values, which is fine.

> I also expect that `coordinates[i] = coord_p;` should copy over the
>   pointers value, letting something like `printf("%d", coordinates[0]->x);` work properly. However, in both cases I'm clearly
>   misunderstanding something.

It copies the value of the pointer (**not** the object that is being pointed to, just the value of the pointer). The object that is pointed to isn't affected by that - it still has the same lifetime, which in this case is until the end of the loop. To actually copy the object being pointed to, do this:

```
*coordinates[i] = *coord_p;
```

This means "set the object pointed to by `coordinates[i]` to the object pointed to by `coord_p`".

Comment: So if I had just 1 pointer to a struct, would I need to call malloc on it?

Comment: Yes, for instance `coord* coordinate = malloc(sizeof(coord));`